# Problem to connect my NXT to Bluetooth. everything else run fine

Tags: nxt, software, bluetooth

I use Windows 11 (64 bit). NXT sw v2.1, NXT firmware 1.31.

I have reinstalled these several times, without success. Everything seems to work fine except to connect via Bluetooth, that fails most of the times.

I suspect it has something to do with my OneDrive connection. During installation of Mindstorms software, it ends up in the cloud (the setting.ini file) although I like to put it locally on my C:.

The PC interact with the NXT, but it fails most of the times. I get a feeling that there is something wrong with the logic or some settings.

Is there anyone out there, that could give me some hints?